# RSpec Randomized Seed NOT Random

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, random, rspec, seed

In the last day or two, all my runs of the same test file use the same random seed even though I didn't specify a seed.

```
    [jim@X230|apoxeia (bootstrap_4_from_responsive_sign_on_and_attornies_clients)]$ bin/rspec spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb  
Running via Spring preloader in process 2564 Environment is test

    Randomized with seed 41303

    ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb: Capybara starting Puma...
    * Version 3.12.0 , codename: Llamas in Pajamas
    * Min threads: 0, max threads: 4
    * Listening on tcp://127.0.0.1:36589 .....

    Top 5 slowest examples (51.21 seconds, 100.0% of total time):   Change Requests GET /change_requests displays the user who logged the change when logged in as admin
        17.91 seconds ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb:155   Change Requests GET /change_requests does NOT add a Change Request when logged in, and field is blank
        17.28 seconds ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb:39   Change Requests GET /change_requests adds a Change Request when logged in and valid params are given
        12.35 seconds ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb:106   Change Requests GET /change_requests displays when logged in
        3.37 seconds ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb:23   Change Requests GET /change_requests redirects when not logged in
        0.30664 seconds ./spec/system/change_requests_spec.rb:17

    Finished in 51.22 seconds (files took 0.45157 seconds to load) 5 examples, 0 failures

    Randomized with seed 41303

    Coverage report generated for RSpec to /home/jim/development/apps/apoxeia/coverage. 322 / 1933 LOC (16.66%) covered.
```

Any ideas on why this would be happening, or where I should start looking?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you explicitly directed it to randomize?

Comment: Could you clarify?  Are you suggesting a specific switch?  BUT, if you mean for example:  Example usage

The defined option is only necessary when you have --order rand stored in a
config file (e.g. .rspec) and you want to override it from the command line.

--order defined
--order rand
--order rand:123, Yes, I've tried --rand.  BUT I think that should not be necessary if I under the doc.

Comment: If you're using rspec-rails, you may need to uncomment a line in your spec_helper.rb

Comment: Try running it with 
`--order rand` or `--order rand:999` and see what that does for you. Wouldn't hurt to grep your project for "41303"

Comment: rspec_helper is setup as described here https://medium.com/skills-matter/find-the-cause-of-randomly-failing-tests-with-rspec-bisect-dfe9ee2a70c2 and here https://ivoanjo.me/blog/2016/09/25/why-you-should-regenerate-your-spec-helper/ Running the tests with a specific seed (--order rand:999) seems to cause that seed to be used based on the output. Interestingly, when I re-run the test without the seed, the seed is reported as the same but sometimes the tests fail differently, suggesting they are not being run the same. More later.

Comment: Does it re-use the same seed if you kill spring with `spring stop` first? This seems to be an ongoing issue (https://github.com/rails/spring/issues/113). It's marked as closed, but people as recently as October report issues still.

Comment: I rebooted my computer (after a day or so) and now no issues.  Crazy.